# Shattered text in Wordpress admin area

Tags: php, html, wordpress, apache2

Couple weeks ago we have migrated one Wordpress website. I was following official Wordpress manual how to migrate website to another domain. I have already done it with several websites without any problems. 
If you want check here is the link: [Official Wordpress migration manual](http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress)

But with our latest website we have a problem with Wordpress admin area. Sometimes labels (menu items texts, headers, link texts) are loaded really strangely. They are consist of some random characters or it's looks like they contain pieces of source code (texts like "abc ref='%s'" instead of "Options" for example). Funny thing is, that links itself work good (for example Options link redirects you to Options panel), so there is no problem with linking just text labels. Here on this screenshot you can see left admin panel when page is loaded correctly and shattered (texts are in Czech language):

[image]

Also strange thing is, that page is mostly loaded completely normally. Only sometimes server has some delay and it takes to load page about 10 seconds. Usually after this delay text is shattered. After refreshing page everything is back to normal.

Do you think it's problem of webhosting server or Wordpress itself ? Have you ever seen this kind of problem with your Wordpress site ?

Comment: Unfortunatly I don't under czechoslovakian, but the picture you have shown.. Looks normal, whats abnormal about it?

Comment: Have you cleared all caches on the server?

Comment: If you got things like `ref='%s'` showing up, have you checked that the server is configured the same way? Does your code have short tags in it, that aren't set up on the server?

Comment: To Daryl: When you look for example on text "Příspěvky" (Posts in English) you see when text is shattered instead of this text you see for instance "měru šípky" which means completely nothing.

Comment: To Andy: Which caches do you mean ? I tried to clear Wordpress cache, but I found that you must use some external plugins for it. Wordpress in default doesn't use cache.

Comment: To andrewsi: Problem is this one could be set differently, because it's not our server, which we usually use (it's webserver of client). When you have shattered text and you refresh page everything goes back to normal. So don't know if short tags are the problem.